# Scanning a port for a particular packet, and create an XML based on the data in the packet

Tags: xml, networking, udp, snmp

I need to create a program/script that constantly scans the outgoing traffic on a computer, searches for an SNMP trap packet (which is on port 162), and based on the description inside that particular packet, an XML with several fields will be created, using the data in the packet in one of the fields.

I've looked at different port scanning solutions, but haven't really found anything that I could use for that particular purpose.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Where to start, and what tools should I use?

Comment: I could suggest Python and twisted (a network oriented framework), but I haven't used it much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the [PCAP library](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm).

Basically you have to filter packets with destination `port 162` (look at the `pcap_compile()` and `pcap_set_filter()` functions) and dissect the SNMP frame of every packet returned by `pcap_next`.

If something useful is found, then dump the content or whatever.

Look at the **"Actual Sniffing"** section in the page linked above. The code in it will catch data with destination or source port 23 (look at the `filter_exp` string). Start from there and tune it according to your needs.

**UPDATE**

If you feel more comfortable with `python`, an interface with `libpcap` exists and it's called [Pcapy](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy)

`Perl` offers the same features with [Net::Pcap library](http://search.cpan.org/~kcarnut/Net-Pcap-0.05/Pcap.pm)

and this is the [Ruby binding](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rubypcap/)

and so for many other modern languages....

Comment: actually there are very few popular languages for which you _can't_ get a libpcap binding